# Members of local System account

Tags: windows, permissions

I'm currently in the process of migrating some shares.  Using my AD account, I was able to navigate to a share and its subfolders.  Looking at the NTFS permissions, I don't belong to any groups that grant "Full" rights.  The only two groups that have "Full" rights are the local administrators (I am not a member) and the System.

Any way to determine exactly how I am able to get "Full" rights without being an explicit member of a group listed in the ACL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Full Control" allows you to do anything imaginable to the folder or its files, like delete them or fiddle with the ACLs. You don't need Full Control to navigate a folder or even to write to it. "List folder / read data" allows you to look around in the folder or read the contents of a file. (Which one it is depends on whether the object in question is a folder or a file.) "Create files / write data" and "Create folders / append data" allow you to do exactly what they say, but you can have that access without having Full Control.

Note that applications running with administrative privileges can use `SeBackupPrivilege` and `SeRestorePrivilege` to read or write anywhere (respectively), no matter what ACLs say. [Read more about privileges at TechNet.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb530716(v=vs.85).aspx)